# Gradle Dependency version property

Tags: maven, gradle

I have multiple dependencies that have same group id and version id.
For example,

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:2.1.0.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.0.RELEASE"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I want to have 2.1.0.RELEASE to be moved into a property defined once.
This is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691980/dependency-version-format-version-xxx), how I would do it in maven.

```
<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I want to get a similar approach with gradle. So far, I tried to have a *gradle.properties* file, and have a property there.

```
springBootVersion=2.1.0.RELEASE
```

*build.gradle* will be

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:${springBootVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

If I use dots `.` in the property name, it will fail to build.
Again, *spring.boot.version* property in gradle.properties fails with error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'spring' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Comment: Why don't you use the spring boot and dependency management plugin, as documented? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/

Comment: 1) I don't like plugins. In maven I did not use any plugin. 2) Also, let's imagine I use not springboot, but a set of third-party libraries and I want to have their version property defined in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot use `spring.boot.version` directly to refer to your property defined with the same name because in [Groovy it actually means](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) `reference the property called **version** in the object called **boot** which is a property of object called **spring**`  instead do this

`...-boot-starter: ${project.ext["spring.Boot.Version"]}"`

This will allow you to add properties with any number of periods in it. For example in your `gradle.properties` you have

`hello.world=heelloooo`

then you can do

`print "The world of stackoverflow says ${project.ext["hello.world"]}"` in your buildscript.

Comment: *It works, thanks.* `compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${project.ext['Spring.Boot.Version']}"`